# IIS 7 Log Files

Tags: iis-7

I a trying to find out where certain events would be logged for IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2

I am looking for logs related to installing packages from the IIS manager ( the thing on the left that says "import package").

You get a details listing in the installer box after the install and I am sure this plus other info must be getting logged.

This info is not found in either iis7.log or inetpub\website\log

Comment: Have you checked the Application Event Log? Not sure if it'll be in there but the Event Log is a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah, nothing much appearing in there. I'm not doing any filtering btw.

Answer (score 1):

I have used CBS logfiles to troubleshoot IIS installation issues. I hope you find your answer there.. `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The "Package" installer is the UI stub from the Web Deployment Tool, so the logs for MSDeploy/WebDeploy will be the logs you're interested in.

I'm not sure where it logs to by default.

Worst-case (ha!) you could use ResMon to watch for file activity by InetMgr and find out that way :) Or use the command-line equivalent with your webdeploy package, specify verbose logging, and your own output file.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on Failed Request Tracing for wmsvc, which can really come in handy for this type of troubleshooting.  Set the following registry keys and restart the "Web Management Service" (WMSvc).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server]
"TracingEnabled"=dword:00000001
"TracingMaxLogFiles"=dword:000003e8
```

After you reproduce it, check the c:\inetpub\logs\wmsvc folder.